# Is there a way not to write cancellation token as a parameter to **each** controller action?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

I have typical (I suppose) Web.API app targeting `net.5`:

- all controllers inherit from my own `ApiControllerBase` class
- `ApiControllerBase` initializes `DbAccess` class according to the particular child controller needs
- all `DbAccess` methods are `async` and should receive (one way or another) `CancellationToken` to pass it down to SQL driver.

Writing `, CancellationToken cancellationToken` in each controller action **and** each `DbAccess` method **and** its call is **very boring**. There simply should not be so much boilerplate text in the sources.

Moreover, I am not very sure, that default `CancellationToken` injected in controller action contains all needed (and only them) triggers. For my purposes there are two: 'http request was cancelled' and 'app is stopping'.

I cooked some ugly solution (described in answer), but still believe there should be something simpler out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is an adequate (I suppose :) way.

1. Convert `DbAccess` class into scoped service, so we'll be able to inject into it.
2. Make scoped `CancellationTokenSourceService` service and inject `IHostApplicationLifetime` and `IHttpContextAccessor` into it.
3. Inject `CancellationTokenSourceService` into `DbAccess` and use `CancellationToken` from the service.
4. Inject `IDbAccess` into controller.

*There is a compromise to make: copy/paste dozens of `DbAccess` methods into interface (proper way) or make a `IDbAccess -> DbAccess` cast (lazy way).*

5. PROFIT!!!

```
public interface IScopedCancellationTokenSourceService
{
    CancellationTokenSource GetSource();
    CancellationToken GetToken();
    void Cancel();
    void CancelAfter(int delay);
}


public class ScopedCancellationTokenSourceService : IScopedCancellationTokenSourceService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    public ScopedCancellationTokenSourceService(IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.RequestAborted ?? default, appLifetime.ApplicationStopped);
    }

/// ... implement IScopedCancellationTokenSourceService interface

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // all disposable be disposed!
        _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, simple part. If all DbAccess methods should receive `CancellationToken`, it should be stored inside some property in the class. Ok, that *was* simple.

But how we pass token to DbAccess? Lets check situation inside controller constructor:

- `IHostApplicationLifetime` is passed via DI, ok
- `HttpContext` is null, duh.

Lets introduce some *ugliness*: property storing `DbAccess` instance in controller class became public (!) and special `ActionFilter` was born to set `CancellationToken` inside it.

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    if (context.Controller is ApiControllerBase controller)
    {
        controller.dbAccess.cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(context?.HttpContext?.RequestAborted ?? default, controller.appLifetime.ApplicationStopping);
    }
}
```

Yes, making some setting method would be somewhat less ugly, but ugly anyway: this method should be public anyway. And another one for cancelling the token in case of emergency.

What is making this approach more difficult to accept and maintain: `IHostApplicationLifetime` could not (?) be injected into `ActionFilter`, so its DI should be copied in all child controllers constructors (and I *hate* copying).